# local notification not working on IOS8 cordova

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios8

notification is working perfectly on the `IOS7(iPhone 4)` but not working on `IOS8 (iPad)`
notification code is:

```
var notificationObject = {
                  id:abc,
                  title:'Prayer Time',
                  message:'Dont forget to buy some flowers.',
                  // repeat:'weekly',
                  date:null,
                 json: JSON.stringify({
                    category: cat,start_time:startTime,end_time:endTime }
                                      )
              };

              var  notificationObjectMonday = jQuery.extend(notificationObject, {
                  date : newactualdate
               });

            window.plugin.notification.local.add(notificationObjectMonday);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//for iOS8 you need to set permission for local notifications
//Registering user notification settings,

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")))
{
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
}
else
{
   //do iOS 7 stuff, which is pretty much nothing for local notifications.
}
return true
```

}